# Как в vscode сделать чтобы в SASS были подсказки классов?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, visual-studio-code

просто у меня их нет, а в обычном css показывает , а тут даже уже написанные классы не подсказывает

Comment: не надо дублировать вопросы